# I am struggling with the with_dict module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to automate VMware builds using Ansible. I am expecting a workflow engine to output a file that would act as a var_file and have all of the objects that can be used to build the VM using the vmware_guest module. It works great until you get to the networks dictionary portion of the module then it falls apart.

I initially tried setting up a vars_file with all of the variables like this:

```
---
validate_certs: no
datacenter: this is the DC
cluster: this is the cluster
folder: "this is the folder"
name: some-server
template: template-name
datastore: "datastore-name"
netname: This is the network
ip: 10.6.6.10
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 10.6.6.1
mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
domain: domain.com
```

However, that returned:

```
argument networks is of type <type 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list: <type 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list"}
```

Where the code fails is on this task:

````
- name: Clone a virtual machine from Windows template and customize
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
    folder: "{{ folder }}"
    name: "{{name }}"
    template: "{{ template }}"
    datastore: "{{ datastore}}"
    networks:
      name: "{{ netname }}"
      ip: "{{ ip }}"
      netmask: "{{ netmask }}"
      gateway: "{{ gateway }}"
      mac: "{{ mac }}"
      domain: "{{ domain }}"```
````

I tried creating a dictionary in the variable file like this:

```
---
validate_certs: no
datacenter: this is the DC
cluster: this is the cluster
folder: "this is the folder"
name: some-server
template: template-name
datastore: "datastore-name"
bnetworks:
 name: This is the network
 ip: 10.6.6.10
 netmask: 255.255.255.0
 gateway: 10.6.6.1
 mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
 domain: americas.global-legal.com
```

And changed the task to include this:

````
networks:
  name: "{{ item.value.name }}"
  ip: "{{ item.value.ip }}"
  netmask: "{{ item.value.netmask }}"
  gateway: "{{ item.value.gateway }}"
  mac: "{{ item.value.mac }}"
  domain: "{{ item.value.domain }}"
  with_dict: bnetworks```
````

And I get this error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> argument networks is of type `<type 'dict'>` and we were unable to convert to list:  cannot be converted to a list"}

There might be more networks in one VM therefor a list is needed. The corect syntax is below

````
- name: Clone a virtual machine from Windows template and customize
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
    folder: "{{ folder }}"
    name: "{{name }}"
    template: "{{ template }}"
    datastore: "{{ datastore}}"
    networks:
      - name: "{{ netname }}"
        ip: "{{ ip }}"
        netmask: "{{ netmask }}"
        gateway: "{{ gateway }}"
        mac: "{{ mac }}"
        domain: "{{ domain }}"```
````

This is a list

```
list:
  - key: value
```

This is a dictionary

```
dictionary:
  key: value
```

This is a list of dictionaries

```
dictionary:
  - key1: value-1-1
    key2: value-2-1
  - key1: value-2-1
    key2: value-2-2
```

---

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined

The indentation of *with_dict* is wrong. The correct syntax is below.

```
vmware_guest:
  ...
  networks:
    - name: "{{ item.value.name }}"
      ip: "{{ item.value.ip }}"
      netmask: "{{ item.value.netmask }}"
      gateway: "{{ item.value.gateway }}"
      mac: "{{ item.value.mac }}"
      domain: "{{ item.value.domain }}"
with_dict: "{{ bnetworks }}"
```

Comment: This worked however, in the version of ansibe I am running I needed to add "{{ }}" around the dictionary name. 

Thank you for your help!